# How to modify BitmapSource in a thread different from the thread create that BitmapSource

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatcher

I create a `BitmapSource` from a background thread (using `Task.Run`), and store it in a member of a class with a name say 'Preview', and make it Freeze so it can be accessed in UI thread.

Then, I want to do some modification to this `BitmapSource`, like rotate it, so I start another thread, and do the Transform, then try to Freeze it again so it can be displayed to user. But when I call the `Preview.Freeze()`, it throws an exception **"The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."**

It cannot freeze, so it cannot be accessed from another thread.
I also notice that when `Preview.Freeze()` is called, `Preview.Dispatcher` becomes `null`.

Here is the sample code:

```
class Test
{
    public BitmapSource Preview { get; set; }

    // This is called in thread A.
    public void Load(string path)
    {
        Preview = new BmpBitmapDecoder(new Uri(path), BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad).Frames[0];
        Preview.Freeze();
    }

    // This is called in another thread B.
    public void Rotate(int angle)
    {
        Preview = new TransformedBitmap(Preview, new RotateTransform(angle));
        Preview.Freeze(); // Throw exception here : "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."
    }

    // This is called in another thread C.
    // Assume there is many other work to do which will cause performance issue
    public void Save(string path)
    {
        // Do some prepare work

        // Save
        using (var fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Create))
        {
            var encoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(Preview));
            encoder.Save(fs);
        }

        // Do some finish work
    }
}
```

I checked the source code of the constructor of the `TransformedBitmap` class, it seems that it just references the previous 'Preview' object which created and freeze from another thread.

How can I make it work? I want to put all the functions like 'Load an image', 'Modify the image', 'Save the image' in background thread, so it will not block the UI.

**Edit:**

What I want to do is make something like Image Editor, so there are many operations on this `BitmapSource`, including Loading, Saving, Transforming to another format and some others. And these would cause performance issue, so I want to put it into a background thread, make the UI show some waiting animation.

**Edit 2:**

I end up with refactor my program. I keep two `BitmapSource` in code. One is loaded from image file in background thread, the other one is used to display lies in UI thread(copied from the other `BitmapSource`, Using UI thread `Dispatcher`). When modify image, modify the `BitmapSource` in UI thread, and log changes to the real image. When finishing modifying and decide to save, those changes are applied to the real image.

I don't know if this is a good idea, it is very appreciated if anyone could give me some other suggestions.

Comment: Do you truly need to rotate the bits of the `BitmapSource` itself?  Would it not be enough to apply a `RotateTransform` to the WPF `Image` control that shows it?

Comment: @Joe Yes, XAML is binding to this `BitmapSource`, I want to change the `BitmapSource` and notify, so the UI can update

Comment: But if you only need to ***present it to the user*** in a rotated format, why not wait until you get the WPF `Image` element itself to handle that?  That would completely obviate the need for any sort of data transformation

Comment: I not only want to present it to user, in fact what I am doing is to create something like **Image Editor** using WPF. It can display, modify, and save modification.  @Joe

Comment: OK, well yes, in that case, setting the `RenderTransform` is not going ot help you.  But maybe you could read the file into a `BitmapImage` and then construct a `WriteableBitmap` from it and then NOT freeze it...  But after that suggestion, I'm all out of moves, I'm afraid

Comment: Thanks Joe, I'll try your advice. @Joe

Comment: Just do not do the image transformations in a background thread. These operation do not actually consume much CPU, because they are chained until a BitmapSource is displayed, which inevitably happens in the UI thread. [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil).

Comment: For the WriteableBitmap: you can of course create new BitmapSources, get their buffer and write that into the BackBuffer of a WritableBitmap that is the Source of an Image element. You will however not be able to change the dimensions of the WritableBitmap, which makes rotations of rectangular (non-square) bitmaps difficult.

Comment: Yes, I can put transformations like rotate, crop into UI thread. But load and save image will cause time if image is big. And there are many other operations, so I'd like to put them into a background thread. @Clemens

Comment: Then do exactly that, put the CPU intensive operations in a Task.Run call (explictly using threads is obsolete), and do the transformations (where you create new BitmapSources) in the UI thread. Problem solved.

Comment: Thanks Clemens, you make me think about my code structure has some problem, I'm trying to do some refactors for my program. @Clemens